# unable to get $scope form name on load

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying the retrieve the form name inside my angularjs component while the form is being loaded as I wanted to set the form state to dirty based on some data  validations that were resolved in to the component. I'm able to access the form name once the form is completely loaded say inside a submit, however i'm unable to do that on the load how can I do that. I'm using ui.router hence the controller name is being set based on the state.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="detail.myForm">
     <button ng-click="detail.submit">
</form>

app.component('myDetail', {
    bindings: {
        alldetails: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/detail.html',
    controllerAs: 'detail',
    controller: function ($state, $transitions, $scope) {
    var detail=this;

     /*validateData in the alldetails here */ 

      $scope.detail.myForm.$setDirty(); // issue here saying undefined

    detail.submit = () =>{
      $scope.detail.myForm.$setPristine() //works without any issue
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens since the DOM isn't ready on your controller's construction. You have to use the `$onInit` callback instead. From [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

> **$onInit()** - Called on each controller after all the controllers on an element have been constructed and had their bindings initialized (and before the pre & post linking functions for the directives on this element). This is a good place to put initialization code for your controller.

Also, it'd be better to inject the `ngFormController` by using the `require` object instead of assigning it to your model.

Here's a [fiddle with a working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rybkwf25/). The relevant code is:

```
.component('myDetail', {
  template: '<h1>Details Component</h1>',
  controllerAs: 'detail',
  // By requiring the form controller, angular will
  // create a 'formCtrl' property on your controller with the
  // ngFormController instance of the parent form.
  require: {
    formCtrl: '^form'
  },
  controller: function() {
    // We can't just acces the formController here, couse it will be
    // undefined, since the dom isn't ready yet. So we have to use the
    // $onInit callback that will be executed by angularjs.
    this.$onInit = function() {
      /*validateData in the alldetails here */
      this.formCtrl.$setDirty();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Leonardo, I couldn't get to the fiddle. App is throwing exception saying require 'form' couldn't be found. I believe form is the name in my example above detail.warehouseForm.

Comment: Hey, the fiddle is working fine (http://fiddle.jshell.net/rybkwf25/). In the example I've provided, you don't need to assign the `ngFormController` to your model, since you can `require` it.